# UK visa overstay

Tags: visas, uk

I have to overstay my 6-month UK tourist visa by three or four days. Should I expect a problem when I fly out with a short overstay?

Comment: It might be a problem the next time you apply especially since they now have automated exit controls. A friend overstayed his UK visa by 10 days a few years ago before automated exit checks. However, that day, they had immigration officers reviewing exiting passengers. She got off with a warning and hasn't had a problem in her next few applications.

Comment: "I have to overstay my 6-month UK tourist visa by three or four days." You almost certainly don't have to do this. And it's probably better for all concerned if you choose not to.

Comment: Saying you have to overstay your visa is almost like saying you have to break the law - very rarely true. You probably won't get into any immediate trouble, but it will go on record, and if you don't explain it on your next visa applications (for at least the next 10 years) you run a big risk of getting those applications refused.

Answer (score 21):

A **valid** reason to overstay would be something like being hospitalized with a life-threatening condition, or the same happening to a relative you're traveling with. In that case, try to get an extension *before* the original visa runs out.

We can't tell you exactly how if we do not know how you came to the UK, and why you have to stay. *Any valid reason would be so deeply personal that you should not post it on a message board.* Find an UK lawyer specialized in immigration cases.

---

Regarding the question, perhaps there will not be much of a problem when you **leave** the UK, but there will be a big problem when you **try to enter** the UK anytime in the future. They will know that you have broken the rules once, and they will think you might do it again.

Comment: Difficulties may be compounded if the original visa application stated that the planned stay in the UK was substantially less than 6 months (regardless of visa validity) and if the supporting documents (financial etc) were commensurate only with a visit much shorter than 6 months.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention that he stayed for 6 months. He may have arrived in the UK only a few days before the visa's expiry. UKVI can't refuse a visa solely on the basis on a short overstay. Only overstays over 28 days are grounds for mandatory refusal. His application should be decided for what is it--an overstay will obviously hurt his credibility and he should decide if it's worth the risk.

Comment: @greatone technically, they can refuse it on that alone - the difference is that they don’t *automatically*.

Comment: Frankly, if I broke my leg a few days before leaving the UK, I would not regard that as "deeply personal" in the least.

Comment: @phoog Breaking a leg is unlikely to be a valid reason, unless it happened on the way to the airport.

Comment: @Tim they have to show on a balance of probabilities that the OP doesn't meet the rules. An overstay may hurt his credibility but if the rest of his application is strong including his reason for visiting, he will be okay.

Comment: @Rob I suppose whether that is true depends on [the severity of the injury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilizarov_apparatus).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to extend your visa as long as the total time you spend in the UK is less than 6 months.

Have you entered the UK at the first day of the visa?

In any case apply before your current visa expires.

Cost: between £1,000 and £1,500. If you go to a premium service centre in person, they'll decide on the same day.

More details: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visit-guidance

Answer (score 0):

No problem *leaving* the country, the UK will want you to depart and will do what they can to push you along.  The *real* problem will arise when you try to later **re-enter the UK,** or enter a country with which the UK shares data.   This overstay will be a big mark against you, because immigration is mainly interested in refusing people likely to overstay or seek employment.

How bad is the mark? I couldn't earthly guess, because it will depend an awful lot on the *other* factors they evaluate about you, your circumstances, and your country of origin.

Is it worth spending $1000+ to fix it?  Due to the above, your future travel plans and your personal situation, I can't guess.  But if the answer is yes, **it's far better heading it off *before the fact* than trying to fix it after an overstay.**  I would start by talking to the UK immigration forces or a lawyer immediately, while you're still legal, and while the most time exists for corrective efforts to run their course.  Don't put it off.